# All IAM users unable to sign in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Created a new AWS account and all IAM users are unable to sign in. "Invalid request" error is given. All users have administrator access policy attached and console access password is enabled. I have also waited it out for 2 days and it's still the same error

Comment: If you think it's an issue with AWS, I guess you should raise a ticket

Comment: I'd suggest trying with a different browser, and even a different network (eg office vs home vs tethered via your phone). If you are all connecting from the same office network or VPN, it might be a networking issue. Are you able to login with your Root credentials?

Comment: Yes, root user account is working great. No issues with that. I have tried to log in on different browsers and also on different devices. I will try on another network and see if that helps